# Which of the following functions on R defines a contraction? M(x) = cos( x/2 ) and M(x) = (1/2) cos(x). Prove your answer.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

Which of the following functions on the real numbers defines a contraction? M(x) = cos(x/2) and M(x) = (1/2)cos(x)? Prove your answer.
I'm having trouble with this in my advanced calculus class. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mean value theorem to conclude your result. 
Notice that for every $x,y$ with $y>x$, there exists some point $c$ such that:

$\cos(y/2)-\cos(x/2)=-1/2\sin(c/2)(y-x)$

Taking absolute values and noting that $|sin(x)|\leq 1$, you have the result.

When you have to solve problems about contractions, the mean value theorem is always useful.